# How to create view based on last record that meets a condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, view

I want to convert the table to given view ( for each case i want the latest time when a specific team acted on it)

TABLE

```
timestamp   teamName    caseNo
8/1/2021    A            1
8/2/2021    A            2
8/3/2021    A            1
8/4/2021    B            1
8/5/2021    B            2
8/6/2021    A            2
```

VIEW

```
caseNo  TeamA (Latest Time)     Team B(Latest Time)
        
1             8/3/2021          8/4/2021
2             8/6/2021          8/5/2021
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So you have used all the right tags which makes me assume you know what you need to do, so show us what you have actually tried

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE VIEW viewname
AS 
SELECT caseNo, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN teamName = 'A' THEN `timestamp` END) teamA, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN teamName = 'B' THEN `timestamp` END) teamB
FROM tablename
GROUP BY caseNo;
```

PS. Used datetime literal format is wrong. You must use `YYYY-MM-DD` pattern or apply `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

Comment: teamA and teamB is hardcoded in SQL query , let there be more than 2 teams then the query become too large and also all team names must be known in prior which may not be the case always.

Comment: @anurag *also all team names must be known* Of course. The output structure of the query is deterministic always. If you need in dynamic output structure then dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement) is the only option.